# Restricting representations to lattices

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lattices

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of the Lie group $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.  Must $V$ remain irreducible when you restrict the action to $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$?  More generally, when you restrict it to other lattices in $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was actually answering a different question.

Comment: Plus the fact that all finite-dimensional representations of semisimple groups are algebraic. 

Comment: @Misha: @Harpo had abbreviated his comment, which initially remarked on the fact you are alluding to. The OP (and I) would probably appreciate a reference to where the fact should be found.

Comment: So it follows from several famous results.  Does anyone want to write an answer that I can accept?  Both of my questions so far have been answered in the comments.  I'm not sure how I should take this -- I've observed elsewhere that people do this with questions they think of as trivial...

Comment: @Misha: Over $\mathbf{C}$ what you write is correct, but over $\mathbf{R}$ you need to impose simply connectedness in additional to semi-simplicity.  The usual counterexample is the inverse of the analytic isomorphism ${\rm{SL}}_n(\mathbf{R}) \rightarrow {\rm{PGL}}_n(\mathbf{R})$ for odd $n > 1$.  The "problem" is that an $\mathbf{R}$-isogeny between connected linear algebraic $\mathbf{R}$-groups can have finite kernel with no nontrivial $\mathbf{R}$-points; over $\mathbf{C}$ this isogeny issue (invisible to Lie algebras) cannot be missed at the level of $\mathbf{C}$-points.

Comment: @Misha: A more basic kind of counterexample is that if the connected semisimple $G$ isn't simply connected then $G(\mathbf{R})$ may be disconnected (e.g., ${\rm{PGL}}_{2n}$ and various other $G$ with "fundamental group" of even order). In such cases the projection from $G(\mathbf{R})$ onto its nontrivial *finite* component group leads to rather non-algebraic representations. This highlights the significance of the connectedness of $G(\mathbf{R})$ when $G$ is simply connected (see my comments on the answer below).

Comment: Dear Sue, it seems to me that different people have different motivations for answering a question in comments. I think that this is often done if they think that what they are going to write will neither justify a reputation gain nor having a question marked as answered, because a better answer is possible, and likely. For example this could well be the case in your other question. Some people rebel against the competition aspect of the reputation system and prefer to write four consecutive comments instead of an answer. Questions that are deemed "too trivial" are usually closed...

Comment: ... instead of being upvoted like yours have been, so there is nothing for you to worry about. For what it's worth, I found your questions and the answers/comments to them instructive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result is essentially the statement of Borel's stability theorem for $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$, see for example
Theorem 4.39 of the following:

http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/books/IntroArithGroups.pdf

Sometimes Borel's stability theorem is phrased in terms of one of the corollaries, which in this case would be that any lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ is Zariski dense. Then to deduce the result one would also have to note that all finite dimensional representations of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$
are algebraic.

Comment: Thanks!  I was previously vaguely aware of the Borel density theorem, but I hadn't connected it to this question and was not aware that it was deduced from something that is almost exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This still lacks a pointer to the algebricity fact, though the Witte-Morris book is most excellent.

Comment: @Igor: Let's show for linear algebraic $\mathbf{R}$-groups $G'$ and $G$ with $G'$ connected semisimple and simply connected, analytic $f:G'(\mathbf{R}) \rightarrow G(\mathbf{R})$ are algebraic. The Lie algebra of $\Gamma_f$ is a perfect subalgebra of $\mathbf{g}' \times \mathfrak{g}$, so by 7.9 in Borel's LAG it arises from a connected closed $\mathbf{R}$-subgroup $H$ of $G' \times G$. Clearly $H$ is semisimple, and $H \rightarrow G'$ is an isogeny, so an isomorphism as $G'$ is simply connected. This gives $G' \rightarrow G$ recovering $f$ on $G'(\mathbf{R})^0 = G'(\mathbf{R})$ (Steinberg!) 

Comment: @Igor (cont'd): At the final step above I am hauling out the big guns: if $G'$ is a connected semisimple $\mathbf{R}$-group that is simply connected then $G'(\mathbf{R})$ is *connected*. The only proof I know is to deduce it from considerations with maximal compact subgroups, Cartan involutions, and a theorem of Steinberg (or topological precursor by Cartan) on Zariski-connectedness of centralizers of semisimple automorphisms of simply connected semisimple groups, way too much to explain here. I would love to know a literature reference (beyond the "classical" anisotropic case).

Comment: The Zariski-density of $G(\mathbf{Z})$ in $G(\mathbf{R})$ for any "split semisimple" group $G$ over $\mathbf{Z}$ (e.g., ${\rm{SL}}_n$) admits a direct proof more elementary than the proof of Borel's theorem. Indeed, by considering pairs of opposite root groups and the open cell structure relative to a positive system of roots for a split maximal $\mathbf{Z}$-torus, we get  $\mathbf{Z}$-subgroups $U \simeq \mathbf{G}_a$ such that the subgroups $U_{\mathbf{Q}}$ generate $G$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. Thus, we just need to note that $\mathbf{Z}$ is Zariski-dense in $\mathbf{G}_a$ over $\mathbf{Q}$!

Comment: @grp: thanks much! I will try to do a literature search to record a decent reference for posterity (though your comments are most enlightening).